# Capturing key stroke

Tags: vimscript

I would like to write a script, maybe even using Python, that captures a key stroke in a Vim window.
Let's say I am in insert mode and I type the letter `g`.
I would like this key stroke to trigger some action, that I configure, while still typing in the letter.
Also, this behaviour should not depend on the key that has been hit (in that case a simple remapping would do).
So, I guess what I'm looking for is some kind of key-hit event I can exploit. Is such a thing available in Vimscript (possibly integrated with Python)?

Comment: What's the status? Does the answer below address your questions?

Answer (score 2):

There is an [auto-command](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html) event [`InsertCharPre`](https://vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#InsertCharPre) that detects entry of any character while in Insert mode yet still inserts it into the buffer. Here's a dead simple example (put this in your vimrc, for instance):

```
augroup InterceptKeyPress
    autocmd!
    autocmd InsertCharPre * :echo localtime()
augroup END
```

You can run any vimscript you want in response to the  event.

A quick test confirms it works as expected. The impact on overall usability is something you'll have to evaluate for yourself. :)

Comment: Ah, the flickering!!!

Comment: Hehe, yeah, that's one of the things I had in mind. Gotta admit, though, I've been playing with it and it runs pretty smoothly for me...but I'm running kind of a beast of a PC so there's that.

Comment: Ah, only flickering in the messages-line :P

Comment: Yeah, with showmode set theres flickering between “INSERT” and “hello”

Comment: I have vim-airline going and it's still like butter. :)